# Cant sign in user in Rspec test ( devise gem )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rspec-rails

I cant find solution for my problem: **cant login user in rspec test**.

I tried this code, following by this link - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Stub-authentication-in-controller-specs

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'factory_girl_rails'

describe "ololo" do

it "blocks unauthenticated access" do

 user = User.create(email: "lol@mail.com", password: "123456")
 request.env['warden'].stub(:authenticate!).
 and_throw(:warden, {:scope => :user})

  visit "/tasks"

  page.should have_content("Signed in successfully.")

end
end
```

/*error*/

```
Failure/Error: page.should have_content("Signed in successfully.")
   expected there to be text "Signed in successfully." in "Task App Home Login You need to sign in or sign up before continuing. Sign in Email Password Remember me Sign upForgot
```

your password? Task App by Denys Medynskyi"

also tried this link - http://codingdaily.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/rails-devise-and-rspec/.

Devise wiki tutorial is also not working for me.

Please, I'm stuck hardly. Help me anyone.

Comment: It was this tutorial that you read? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-(and-rspec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your error message, I guest one possible reason is you created hard record of User to test db. You may have run this test once, so in second time this creation fails because record with same email exists.

You've required FactoryGirl. Why don't you use FactoryGirl to create the fixture data?

In `spec/factories/user.rb`

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email: "lol@mail.com"
    password "123"
  end
end
```

In your test, write

```
FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

#### Add

Comparing with the tut you lack two steps:

1. You need to use FactoryGirl to replace the hard created record, as writing above.
2. You need to execute the `sign_in` step before visit the private page.

Maybe you would be good with #2 only if you cleared the db after tests. Anyway factory data is recommended over hard data.

Comment: I will try what you are saying and change my question.

Comment: How I can clear test database, because I get validation errors ?

Comment: Use `rake db:test:prepare` to clear db manually. Also look at the two lines in tut: `user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)`, `sign_in user`, the two are necessary.

Comment: Fails. ` Failure/Error: page.should have_content("Signed in successfully.")
       expected there to be text "Signed in successfully." in "Task App Home Login You need to sign in or sign up before continuing. Sign in Email Password Remember me Sign upForgot your password? Task App by Denys Medynskyi"`